# Lucene Search Item start location

Tags: content-search, lucene

We are having the below item structure in sitecore and using Lucene Index,

- Home

  -- Products A Repository

  - Product 1
  - Product 2
  - Product 3

  -- Products B Repository

  - Product 1
  - Product 2
  - Product 3

Products A & Product B repository items is using Same template called product.
We have created new common custom index start location we set as Home.

we are trying to use the below code

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);
using (var searchContext = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var searchText ="Product";
    var items = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                .Where(x => x.Content.Equals(searchText) && x.Language == query.Language)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
                .GetResults();
}
```

reference: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/developing/developing_with_sitecore/search_and_item_buckets/linq_to_sitecore

but we are not sure how to set the Index Search Start location to search the item from the particular repository.

Update:

Your Solution Works well , i marked as answer

Answer (score 5):

In the SearchResultItem class, you can find Paths property, which holds ancestor id's.

```
[IndexField("_path")]
[DataMember]
[TypeConverter(typeof (IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]
public virtual IEnumerable<ID> Paths { get; set; }
```

You can pass start location (eg: in your case Product A Repository item id or Product B Repository item id) to Path,

```
 var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);
 using (var searchContext = index.CreateSearchContext())
 {
     var searchText = "Product";
     var items = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                 .Where(x => x.Paths.Contains(new ID("{}")) && x.Content.Equals(searchText) && x.Language == query.Language)
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Updated)
                 .GetResults();
 }
```